# Export blob data to file in django

Tags: python, django, blob, wav

I am sending a blob with user mic input from angular to a django api endpoint. The blob is a 8000Hz mono wav file.

```
// Prepare data
var data = new FormData();
data.append('section_item_id', id);
data.append('blob', blob);
```

api view:

```
def compare_audio(request):
    print dict(request.data)
    return Response({'status' : random.choice(['true', 'false'])})
```

I can see the blob is sent with that print. For testing purposes, I'd like to export the blob I get in django, and save it to a file on the server. How?

Answer (score 0):

From data you can create wav using scipy:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import math

file_name="another.wav"
rate=8000
data2 = np.asarray(request.data, dtype=np.int16)

scipy.io.wavfile.write(file_name,rate,data2)
```

You can use mod_xsendfile for serving files from django view using apache, for example:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='audio/wav')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
return response
```